# Check if relation exists in database via pivot table

Tags: mysql, laravel, optimization, eloquent, inner-join

**situation**

User can belong to multiple organizations, linked via a pivot table called `employees`

Models at play: `User`, `Employee` & `Organizations`

Relevant database columns:

```
users
- id

employees
- user_id
- organization_id

organizations
- id
```

**goal**

An efficient way to check if user `1` and user `2` share at least one `organization_id` in the `employees` table

**usecase**

Api endpoint `/api/v1/user/#` returns additional metadata regarding the user.

Using a `policy`, it checks if the current user and the user id from the url are the same, or that they are both employee in at least one organization, the `organization_id` is not known at this stage, all that matters is that it matches.

**example A**

user A (`1`) is employee of organization foo (`1`)

user B (`2`) is employee of organization bar (`2`)

employee table thus has the following records:

```
+-----------------+---------+
| organization_id | user_id |
+-----------------+---------+
|               1 |       1 |
|               2 |       2 |
+-----------------+---------+
```

in this example the query should return a false result, since there is no shared `organization_id` between user A and B

**example B**

user A (`1`) is employee of organization foo (`1`)

user A (`1`) is employee of organization foobar (`3`)

user B (`2`) is employee of organization bar (`2`)

user B (`2`) is employee of organization foobar (`3`)

employee table thus has the following records:

```
+-----------------+---------+
| organization_id | user_id |
+-----------------+---------+
|               1 |       1 |
|               2 |       2 |
|               3 |       1 |
|               3 |       2 |
+-----------------+---------+
```

in this example the query should return a true result, since there is a shared `organization_id` between user A and B

**policy code**

```
/**
 * Determine whether the user can view the model.
 *
 * @param  \App\User  $user
 * @param  \App\User  $model
 * @return mixed
 */
public function view(User $user, User $model)
{
    if ($user->is($model)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        // check if users share at least one organization 
    }
}
```

**code that works but does not look efficient**

```
foreach ($user->organizations()->with('users')->get() as $organization) {

    if ($organization->users->where('id', $model->id)->first()) {
        return true;
    }

}

return false;
```

**experimental code with joins instead of something done with laravel models**

```
        \Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::table('employees as auth_employee')
        ->join('employees as other_employee', 'other_employee.organization_id', '=', 'auth_employee.organization_id')
//        ->join('organizations', 'organizations.id', '=', 'organizations.id')
        ->where('auth_employee.id', 1)
        ->where('other_employee.id', 2)
        ->get()
```

**requested solution**

An efficient query to get a (castable to) boolean result result wether or not 2 users share at least one `organization_id` on the `employees` table, 'bonus points' for using the laravel models / query builder.

**footer**

Thanks for reading, here is a potato:

Comment: Thanks for the potato, but you can you let us know what you want here?  Do you want a raw MySQL query to solve your problem, do you want Laravel/PHP code, or something else?

Comment: Preferably a mysql query in the format of the laravel query builder or as a model relation @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: how about you take all the organization id from both the users and check for a php `in_array` method? won't that be a solution? since you dont want the organization id's that will be enough right?

Comment: Could you show us the _exact_ output you want from this query, in terms of values?

Comment: @KevinRED it is an option, but i am currently looking to do it as a query, as to not pull in to much data from the database

Comment: @Quezler ok got it

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen an output that can be interpreted as a boolean, e.g. an array of occurances that can be `count() > 0`ed

Comment: I attempted an answer below, in raw MySQL; have a look.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks for that answer, before i mark one as accepted i plan to wait just a little while longer to see if a more laravel-ish answer is added, but i'll upvote it in advance 

Comment: Just to double check, you're wanting to see if the `$user` and `$model` share an organisation, or just if the user shares an organisation with anyone else?

Comment: @RossWilson to see if `$user` is related to `$model` via a shared `organization_id` in the `employees` table, but the id of the `organization` is not know during the request, all that matters is that they are both part of at least one organization that they are both an employee of

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have a users relationship set up in your `Organization` model, you could use the [whereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) method:

```
$user->organizations()->whereHas('users', function ($query) use($model) {
    $query->where('users.id', $model->id);
})->exists();
```

Comment: `Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous`

Comment: @Quezler I've updated my answer to include the table name in the where clause.

Comment: Works like a charm, but does this do just one query or does it repeat the callback for each user/etc in the database?

Comment: @Quezler It will be just one query.

Answer (score 1):

As a raw query, I would probably use `EXISTS` here, but since you would need to port any query to Laravel/PHP code, I might suggest using a self-join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    e1.user_id, e2.user_id
FROM employees e1
INNER JOIN employees e2
    ON e1.organization_id = e2.organization_id AND e1.user_id = 2
WHERE
    e1.user_id = 1;
```

This would just return the `user_id` pair of values `(1, 2)`.  If you wanted a query to return all pairs of distinct users sharing at least one organization, you could rewrite this query to this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    e1.user_id, e2.user_id
FROM employees e1
INNER JOIN employees e2
    ON e1.organization_id = e2.organization_id AND e1.user_id <> e2.user_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

The most readable example I can think of would be to put something like this in the user model:

```php
public function isColleagueWith(User $user): bool
{
    return $this->organizations->intersectByKey($user->organizations)->count() > 0;
}
```

Usage is easy to read and understand:

```php
$userA->isColleagueWith($userB);
```

If you wanted to use less DB queries, you could query the pivot table directly instead. Here you an get all organizations that employ the two users and check if the list contains any duplicate organization ids.

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class Employees extends Pivot
{
    public function areColleagues(int $userIdA, int $userIdB): bool
    {
        $employments = $this->where('user_id', $userIdA)
            ->orWhere('user_id', $userIdB)
            ->get('organization_id');

        return $employments->count() > $employments->unique()->count();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```php
Employees::areColleagues($userIdA, $userIdB);
```

Comment: If you are already getting the users, it is just one extra query to get the organizations too by eager loading the organizations relation, so then you could easily employ solution nr 1. If you just have two user IDs it is simpler with solution nr 2.

Answer (score 1):

To check if users 1 and 2 share one or more organizations:

```
SELECT EXISTS (
          SELECT 1 FROM employees AS a
                   JOIN employees AS b  USING(organization_id)
                   WHERE  a.user_id = 1
                     AND  b.user_id = 2;
```

Have both of these indexes:

```
(user_id, organization_id)
(organization_id, user_id)
```